# Equivalent of a C union in Python?

Tags: python, union

Say I'm having a following code in C:

```
union u_type
{
    uint32_t data;
    uint8_t  chunk[4];
} 32bitsdata;

32bitsdata.chunk[0] = some number;
32bitsdata.chunk[1] = some number;
32bitsdata.chunk[2] = some number;
32bitsdata.chunk[3] = some number;

printf("Data in 32 bits: %d\n", 32bitsdata.data);
```

How could I do similar thing in ython?

I'm trying to read a binary file (byte by byte) - already got it working, and combining every 3 bytes into one int. Heard struct would do the trick, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: You can just store four numbers inside four variables, Python doesn't require types...

Comment: That's not the point I'm asking. Union is convenient in this way because it could convert all 4 of the 8 bits to one 32 bits. I'm doing a project that needs to parse the data into bytes, so that's why I need this similar function in python.

Comment: But because there's no types, there's therefore no need for a union in Python. I mean, you can create your own class for this, but I don't see any reason why.

Comment: Take a look at the `struct` module

Comment: There's no use for a `union` in Python.  In Python, _data_ has a type, but _variables_ don't.  This means that the variable-type / data-type mismatch that `union` is supposed to work around simply can't happen.

Comment: If you want to store _n_ bytes, there are standard data types for exactly that.  [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) is an immutable array of bytes, and [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) is a mutable array of bytes.  (See also: the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).)

Comment: Thanks guys. Python is not my language, but I like to sometimes do python scripting for post-processing.
Back to my question, I'm trying to read a binary file (byte by byte) - already got it working, and combining 3 bytes to one int. Heard struct would do the trick, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: @shjnlee it's part of the standard library. It should be easy to grasp if you have a C background. Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). You probably want to look at `struct.iter_unpack`

Comment: I could probably fix my example but I don't think it would fit OP's requirements adequately.

Comment: I don't really know C except cursorily, don't really have a good graps of unions. What exactly do you want to do with your raw bytes?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp: "Python doesn't require types" - How does this get together with Python being strongly typed? You confuse dynamic typing with "no typing"!

Comment: XY-problem. The code is problematic in both languages. Use bitshifts/masking in both, C and Python!

Comment: @toohonestforthissite - the code is problematic b/c alignment of union members is not guaranteed by the standard. One could use extensions like `packed` attribute. Then there is the problem of endianness. But, for a given architecture and a given (well documented) compiler, what other problem (if any) do you see in this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint)?

```python
from ctypes import (
        Union, Array, 
        c_uint8, c_uint32, 
        cdll, CDLL
) 

class uint8_array(Array):
    _type_ = c_uint8
    _length_ = 4

class u_type(Union):
    _fields_ = ("data", c_uint32), ("chunk", uint8_array)

# load printf function from Dynamic Linked Libary libc.so.6 (I'm using linux)
libc = CDLL(cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')._name)
printf = libc.printf

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize union
    _32bitsdata = u_type()
    # set values to chunk
    _32bitsdata.chunk[:] = (1, 2, 3, 4)
    # and print it
    printf(b"Data in 32 bits: %d\n", _32bitsdata.data)
```

Comment: Very nice. I figured there was something in ctypes for an exact translation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you would do. First, let's create the raw bytes we need, I'll cheat and use `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array((8,4,2,4,8), dtype=np.uint32)
>>> arr
array([8, 4, 2, 4, 8], dtype=uint32)
>>> raw_bytes = arr.tobytes()
>>> raw_bytes
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00'
```

These could have easily been read from a file. Now, using the `struct` module is trivial. We use the unsigned int format character `'I'`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> list(struct.iter_unpack('I', raw_bytes))
[(8,), (4,), (2,), (4,), (8,)]
```

Note, each time we iterate we get back a tuple, since our struct has one member, it is a list of singleton tuples. But this is trivial to get into a flat python list:

```
>>> [t[0] for t in struct.iter_unpack('I', raw_bytes)]
[8, 4, 2, 4, 8]
```

Another alternative is to read them into an `array.array`:

```
>>> import array
>>> my_array = array.array('I', raw_bytes)
>>> my_array
array('I', [8, 4, 2, 4, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing fancy numerical manipulation, you'd probably want to use the numpy library anyway, so consider the "view" method of numpy's ndarray type. The original ndarray can be viewed *and* modified via the view-array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.uint32([1234567890])
>>> b = a.view(np.uint8)
>>> print(a)
[1234567890]
>>> print(b)
[210   2 150  73]
>>> b[2] = 10
>>> print(*b)
210 2 10 73
>>> print(*a)
1225392850
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about C union, but if your objective is to group 3 bytes into an int, you could use Python [struct.unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) instead.

```
import struct

chunk = bytearray()
chunk.append(0x00)   # some number
chunk.append(0xc0)   # some number
chunk.append(0xff)   # some number
chunk.append(0xee)   # some number

# Convert to a 32-bit unsigned int.
# You didn't specify the byte-order, so I'm using big-endian.
# If you want little-endian instead, replace the '>' symbol by '<'.
data = struct.unpack('>I', chunk)[0]  # unpack returns a tupple, but we only need the first value

print(hex(data))  # the terminal prints 0xc0ffee
```