# Filling array in Python - from C equivalent

Tags: python, arrays, c, union

I want to write in python something like this:
Fill the array with values like bellow and send it like bytes array.

```
#define ADDR_1    0x5
#define ADDR_2    0x1288
#define CMD       0x63

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t addr1;
  uint8_t addr2[2];
  uint8_t cmd;

}tAddress;

typedef union
{
  tAddress Values;
  uint8_t  array[4]  
 
}Temp

Temp packet;
packet.tAddress.addr1 = ADDR_1;
packet.tAddress.addr2 = ADDR_2;
packet.tAddress.cmd = CMD;

SendBytes(packet.array);
```

Could you help me please how to do this?

Best regards, Jan.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383771/equivalent-c-union-in-python

Comment: I just fill the array like that: <code> packet=[ADDR1.to_bytes(1,byteorder = 'big'), ADDR2.to_bytes(2,byteorder = 'big'),CMD.to_bytes(1,byteorder = 'big')] </code>
but now I need take this packet and pass it to function with bytearray param -how can I do that?
def crc16(self, data : bytearray, offset , length):